# What is this error on DRC Cadence layout

Tags: layout, cadence, drc

I'm doing the layout of an amplifier on Cadence. I've run the DRC error checker and I don't understand what message is this, can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is an #INFO message. What makes you think it is an error? For the same kit, can you show an actual DRC error that gets caught?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error, but rather an informational message. It's standard to include these with some rules decks, since you are immediately provided context (what rule deck, what version, etc) right in the result list.

Additionally, these can be used to remind designers of rules that cannot be checked automatically by that deck. For example, my DRC deck includes a rule called DRM.R.1, reminding me to run other important DRC decks (such as my wire-bonding rules, antenna, MiM, etc).