# How can I find the errors on my layout?

Tags: analog, layout, cadence, drc

I am losing my mind not being able to find the error on my layout. I feel like I am looking for a nail in the mud.

I am getting the DRC error

: MET1 pin outside met1

But I look and look and LOOK and can't see what pin is outside met1 drawing. I've zoomed on every one of my 5 pins and they are ALL inside MET1 so what am I missing ?! Where do I look?

[image]

I know it is hard to see the image like that, but I am desperate for an answer, I've been looking into the screen for hours and have no idea what to do more.

---

Note:  While the layouts look very similar, this is not the same as my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/604107/what-is-this-error-on-drc-cadence-layout), and I am obtaining a different error, hence why this is a different post.

---

Comment: Clarifications - which layer (by color/pattern) is actually Met1? which DRC tool? Does it provide coordinates in any of its outputs? Does pressing Shift+F to see evaluated PCells (Ctrl+F to undo) help? If you're using Assura, does enabling highlight for the violation show a marker (after zooming in/out to refresh the screen)?

Comment: Granger Obliviate - Hi, I have added your explanation of why this question isn't a duplicate and re-opened this question. (I have also deleted the copy & paste of this question which you opened, as that now has no purpose, due to this question being re-opened.) If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you @SamGibson

Comment: @nanofarad with all this confusion of the question being closed/ duplicated/ reopened again I've missed your remarks. I am sorry! I hope you are still able to help me!. Met1 is the blue one, red is poly, that reddish/pink is the biasing of the n-well and the p-substrate. I am using Assura DRC Tool. It doesn't seem to provide coordinates. I will try Shift+F. The violation is supposed to appear in green but I can't see it. Maybe it isn't enabled? Do you want a screenshot from that window?

Comment: @nanofarad Ok so Shift+S just shows the transistors in more detail, I've actually used them like that when perfoming the connections. Do you think maybe it was something on the transistors?

Comment: More screenshots (higher res if possible) would be good. I don't see anything that stands out in your screenshot.

Comment: @nanofarad I just redid the whole thing, it was easier than looking for the mistake, as it is nearly impossible. This time I've kept performing DRC after DRC to see if he complained and he only complained when I wasn't connecting the nwell, so now no errors. But thank you anyway for your help and patience!

Comment: By the way @nanofarad when I run LVS the layout and schematics match (yeah!) BUT it says I have a DRC Violation, which I assume is due to that "note" that comes from the manufacturer that I asked about in a previous question

Comment: @GrangerObliviate No problem, glad it's resolved now. I would check the list of DRC violations to confirm if it's actually just the "note", rather than a real violation (since IIRC LVS can also raise DRC-like errors during extraction if it can't make sense of certain geometries)

Comment: @GrangerObliviate - Hi, If you have solved (or worked around) the issue and don't need any further replies, can you write an answer to document the solution, or at least what you did to work around the problem? (You would be able to accept a [self-answer](/help/self-answer) as soon as 48 hours has passed since you asked the question.) That way, we don't get nagged by the site for having a question left without an answer and search engines will be able to index the answer to help future readers. Thanks.